# How to change box name in Chef kitchen.yml?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I have created my `kitchen.yml` in the following way:

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  customize:
    memory: 2048

driver_config:
  require_chef_omnibus: true
  use_vagrant_berkshelf_plugin: true

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  chef_omnibus_url: http://box-url/install.sh

platforms:
  - name: prod.abc.com
    driver:
      box_url: http://abc.box
    run_list:
      - role[new_role]

suites:
  - name: default
```

In the above `kitchen.yml`, I get the hostname of the machine as `default-prodabccom`. However, I want the hostname to be `prod.abc.com`

What changes should i made in my `kitchen.yml` to get the correct name?

Comment: Do you want the name of the box (in virtualbox) or the hostname of the running OS to be changed?

Comment: when i run `kitchen converge`  i get the message `Converging <default-prodabccom>...` I want it to be `Converging <prod.abc.com>...`  I believe with this change the hostname will be changed to `prod.abc.com`

Comment: It seems like even though i am including `dot` , still it is not considering it

Comment: not sure why it was downvoted, this is exactly what I need to know, and sounds like a pretty general use case for kitchen-vagrant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hostname of the Guest System

In order to define the hostname of the operating system running inside the VM (cf. `/etc/hostname`), use the [`vm_hostname`](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/blob/236970afa3d64558ca7c7dfbff2d55269b10f4d8/templates/Vagrantfile.erb#L25-L27) option of the *kitchen-vagrant* driver:

```
platforms:
  - name: prod.abc.com
    driver_config:
      vm_hostname: prod.abc.com
```

### Name of the Test-Kitchen Suite/Platform

To rename the suite-platform combination shown in `Converging <default-prodabccom>`, you can only play with `name` of `suite` and `platform`, i.e., to get `production-abccom`. This name is [computed here in test-kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/blob/master/lib/kitchen/instance.rb#L44-L46) and, e.g., all dots are stripped, which cannot simply be changed.

Nevertheless, if I understand it right that you want to change this name: it makes little sense to me. Don't change that.

### Name of the VM in VirtualBox

The name of the VM (e.g. `kitchen-default-prodabcom_..default_1234..`) is derived [here in kitchen-vagrant](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/blob/236970afa3d64558ca7c7dfbff2d55269b10f4d8/lib/kitchen/driver/vagrant.rb#L396-L398) and cannot easily be changed.

Comment: I am using OHAI `node[hostname]` in my chef recipe. And, it is giving value as `prod` and stripping out the remaining values. I want the value to be shown as `prod.abc.com`

Comment: You get `prod` already? Use `node[fqdn]`, as you obviously don't want the host name, but the FQDN.

Comment: Good to hear. In combination with `vm_hostname` or even without?

Comment: in combination with `vm_hostname`

Comment: Okay, that's what I expected. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: `node['machinename']` is the return of /bin/hostname, while `node['fqdn']` will go through forward and reverse DNS lookup (`hostname -f` behavior) which may not work for virts.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question because I was in the scenario where I am testing a number of kitchen enabled repos, each containing a number of platforms. e.g.

1. elasticsearch

   - centos-6
   - centos-7
2. java

   - centos-6
   - centos-7

and you can give those machines their own ip by virtualbox when they are spun up like so;

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  network: 
    - ["private_network", { type: "dhcp" }]
```

This facilitates testing, if something has failed and then you can get to the box directly. And you can use the vagrant `HostManager` plugin to keep your `/etc/hosts` updated with the current ip address.

So you can go http://default-centos-74.vagrantup.com in a local browser to check that instance. You can also name your suites in such a way that it leads to unique names for each each, across repos, for example prefixing each like so;

```
suites:
  - name: elasticsearch-default
```

and in other other `.kitchen.yml`

```
suites:
  - name: java-default
```

which still leads to useful naming;

http://elasticsearch-default-centos-74.vagrantup.com

However whats happended recently is that chrome and firefox have started to enforce [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) which makes trying to get to non-HTTPS local sites, mapped using `/etc/hosts` a PITA.

The main thing is to get rid of the vagrantup.com suffix. However that is hard coded in, and the only option for over writing it is in `.kitchen.yml` which is unfortunate, because that doesn't know the suite and platform at the point it generates the Vagrantfile, so it's not much use.

You can use chef/ansible to rename the box, but that is not very nice. The solution I came up with is like this;

you can set a custom `Vagrantfile.erb` in `.kitchen.yml` ;

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  network: 
    - ["private_network", { type: "dhcp" }]
  vagrantfile_erb: Vagrantfile.erb
```

Then copy that `Vagrantfile.erb` out of the gem on your local box into the root of your test-kitchen repo. Mine was at `/home/user1/.gem/ruby/gems/kitchen-vagrant-1.3.0/templates/Vagrantfile.erb`

And then you set arbitrary names to your boxes by changing it at line 36;

```
c.vm.hostname = "<%= @instance.name %>.<%= 
config[:kitchen_root].split('/')[-1]  %>.testbox"
```

or you can modify it like so, and allow over riding from the .kitchen.yml config

```
36c36
<   c.vm.hostname = "<%= config[:vm_hostname] %>"
---
>   c.vm.hostname = "<%= @instance.name %>.<%= config[:var_domain] ? config[:var_domain] : config[:kitchen_root].split('/')[-1]  %>.<%= config[:var_suffix] ? config[:var_suffix] : "vagrantup.com"  %>"
99d98
<
```

https://gist.github.com/tolland/fe01eb0f46d26850cc5c98e167578f7b

And then you set arbitrary names to your boxes by setting `var_suffix` and `var_domain` in .kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  network: 
    - ["private_network", { type: "dhcp" }]
  vagrantfile_erb: Vagrantfile.erb
  #var_domain: sometingsomething
  var_suffix: testbox
```